# Would these led bulbs cause a problem with this ballast?

Tags: light-fixture, led, ballast

A little over two years ago I replaced the 4 florescent bulbs in my overhead light fixture with 4 LED bulbs that I believed would work.  The LEDs worked great with no problems at all.

After about 2 years of usage the bulbs started strobing and blinking and finally one of them overheated and completely failed.

**bulb details**

The bulbs are marked as follows:
[image: LED bulb details]

That's :
Substitute for 32W 48T8 or 40W 48T12

**Ballast Details**

[image: ballast details]

**Should These Work?**

Would you have expected these to fail?  Are the incorrect?
Or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes those lamps are correct for that wattage ballast,
Since they worked for 2 years the ballast may have failed. Hopefully the lamps are universal and you can “direct wire” them.

Preheat ballast usually are not a good match with LED’s but there is not enough info there to know what type of ballast that is.

If the lamps have the direct wire or ballast bypass option they may work with the ballast removed, verification of the lamp type and wiring method will be needed to know if it can be done. The lamps I purchase are universal they work with most ballasts and can be direct wired and there are double ended and single ended versions.

If the lamps did fail as is common with cheap lamps it was probably the driver circuit. I have found led lamps & fixtures that are not DLC or design light consortium approved rarely last very long DLC. lamps are guaranteed for 5 years.

Comment: thanks for your great answer.  I went out and bought four new linear leds and put them in and tried them. They began to strobe so I turned them off and took them out immediately.  Next, I went back to store, bought a new ballast and put it in and now the new leds work perfectly.  Apparently it was the ballast that went bad.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Why put in a new ballast? LEDs generally work better with the ballast just removed / bypassed.

Comment: Raddevus If the advice was helpful a check mark accepts the answer and others can find the accepted answer that may have the same issue  @john watte slow down not all LED’s work without a ballast there are 3 different types of led replacement lamps. Universal will work with or without a ballast. Ballast bypass, the ballast must be removed. Plug n play require the ballast plugging a plug in play directly to the line will usually fry the driver.